# I know Button ID integer value.Create new button object with ID

Tags: android, button, dynamic

For Example:

```
for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
{
    final Button btn = new Button(oyun.this);
    btn.setId(i);
    layout.addView(btn);
}
```

the dynamic button add to layout after

```
  for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
  Button btn=(Button)findViewById(i);
  btn.setText(Integer.toString(i));
  }
```

What do I need for a process similar to

How can I control this way Button.

Comment: What do you mean by `control`?

Comment: I created a second button object not true.
How do I make it

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout adddynamicbuttons =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynamicbuttons);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        Button bt=new Button(MainActivity.this);
        bt.setText(""+i);
        bt.setId(i);
        adddynamicbuttons.addView(bt);
    }
```

> try this, it works fine